# Creating a Controller using Nodejs and massive

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, controller, massivejs

Using massive postgreSQL driver , I am able to connect to postgreSQL and get records from database.

```
var Massive = require("massive");

var connectionString = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres";
var db = Massive.connectSync({connectionString : connectionString});


  db.query("Select * from company", function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This code logs data to console window. But I want to create an end point and send the response back to the client.

Tried for sample on how to create controller using Node and massive , but not much luck.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a HTTP endpoint, is that correct?

For this, you will probably want to use [express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

There are plenty of great tutorials out there on create a HTTP server with express, however this will get you started:

Install the express module via the node package manager.

From your terminal/command line, type:

```
cd project-name
npm install express --save
```

Modify your node server to the following:

```
var Massive = require("massive")
  , http = require("http") // import http
  , express = require("express") // import express
  , app = express(); // instantiate your app

/* database config */
var connectionString = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres";
var db = Massive.connectSync({connectionString : connectionString});

/* http routes */
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  // req is the request object
  // res is the response object
  db.query("Select * from company", function (err, data) {
    // send a http response with status code 200 and the body as the query data. 
    res.status(200).send(data);
  });
});

/* listen in port 3000 */
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

This application will listen on port 3000, and respond to requests to '/', eg http://localhost:3000/. The database will be queried and the result will be send as the response to the HTTP request.